# Safely building a custom thread as base for descendants

Tags: multithreading, delphi, inheritance, delphi-xe2

I'm writing a custom thread which includes some added functionality. The part I'm confused about is how to handle the `Execute` procedure, while still expecting it to be descended into more inherited implementations.

My custom thread is overriding the `Execute` procedure and adding some of my own stuff, such as events `OnStart`, `OnStop` and `OnException`, as well as looping capabilities. I'm not sure how to design this in a way that expects it to be further used in a further inherited thread.

How do I make it possible to further inherit this custom thread while maintaining the `Execute` functionality?

Here's the execute procedure as I have overridden it...

```
procedure TJDThread.Execute;
begin
  Startup;
  try
    while not Terminated do begin
      if assigned(FOnExecute) then
        FOnExecute(Self);
      if not FRepeatExec then
        Terminate
      else
        if FExecDelay > 0 then
          Sleep(FExecDelay);
    end;
  finally
    Cleanup;
  end;
end;
```

I'm intending for `FOnExecute` to be actually an event of the thread, which is more-so a replacement of inheriting the `Execute` procedure - similar to how a service works. I don't think this is the right way to go... How do I make sure this is coded in a safe manner? I'm open to suggestions to another approach than an event - so long as it's aimed at the goal of making a custom `TThread` which can be inherited and further executed.

This custom thread I'm making includes some additional capabilities which don't come with the original `TThread` and yet will be extremely useful for many future projects. The additional capabilities are specifically `OnStart` and `OnStop` events (similar to how a service works), `CoInitialize` built in (and only used if told to, default = false), Repeated execution (default = false), and delay between executions (default = 0).

Comment: You don't make a thread thread-safe, you make code that could access (global) resources thread-safe. Don't worry about the Execute, if you were to make the entire Execute thread-safe, you can just as well do away with threads.

Comment: Maybe *thread safe* wasn't the right term - I mean how do I make sure this thread is safely coded?

Comment: You're reinventing the worker thread?  Why not use OmniThreadLibrary? Been there, done that, it's HARD.  If you proceed down this road, have a look at OmniThreadLibrary's unit tests, and ask yourself if you trust your code not to be full of concurrency issues, race conditions, and even deadlocks.

Comment: @WarrenP I'm already almost done, I just need to make the main `Execute` procedure in a way that it can be descended safely. **Please** stop trying to send me in a complete opposite direction, I've tried `OTL` and there is way *too much* there.

Comment: Well, in my humble opinion, you're doing it completely wrong above.  I don't necessarily think renaming the Execute method to Run is enough, but it would work for now. I'm also not sure why you need that SYnchronize(SYNC_ONTerminate) when TThread already has an on-terminate event.

Comment: You don't see benefits because you don't know what I plan to do with it. I know I'm doing it wrong above, that's why I'm asking how to do it right :P And I'm adding special handling for when `SYNC_OnTerminate` is called

Comment: That makes your question less valuable here, because nobody else is psychic who comes along later. This is 50% a Help Jerry site, and 50% a Help People Who Come After Jerry site. Please make an effort to explain why things are the way they are.

Comment: When I do explain details, as you suggest, people complain that I'm asking too much. So what to do?

Comment: Calling Terminate when your thread already has terminated seems wrong.

Comment: The trick is to ask questions that make sense, and contain enough information to see exactly WHAT you're asking and if it's oddball (which is your problem here) then WHY you need to do the oddball thing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That was actually going to be another question, is it safe to call `Terminate` on a thread more than once?

Comment: @Jerry Sure it is. Rather pointless to do so, but benign. Do you have the VCL source code? You can read this stuff yourself.

Comment: @WarrenP I still don't see any reason why I should have to explain *why* I'm doing this. My question explains exactly enough information to demonstrate what I'm trying to do without going overboard. How can I give it *more sense* when I don't know what doesn't make sense to you? Everyone else seems to understand what I'm asking.

Comment: All the answers show things that are wrong with your approach but do not point out the actual solution to your actual problem because you haven't stated what the problem is clearly enough.

Comment: The problem is I (didn't) know how to properly accommodate for the `Execute` procedure. Based on the answers, now I do. It's just a matter of trying each one and seeing which is best fit for my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Rob. Don't use an event, use a virtual method. But even if you were to use the event and employ its "assignedness" to signal whether there is work to be done, you would need to protect the FOnExecute member as it can be set from different threads.

In one of our thread classes we use commands to do something similar:

```
procedure TCommandThread.SetCommand(const Value: ICommand);
begin
  Lock;
  try
    Assert(not IsAvailable, 'Command should only be set AFTER the thread has been claimed for processing');

    FCommand := Value;

    if Assigned(FCommand) then
      MyEvent.SetEvent;
  finally
    Unlock;
  end;
end;
```

As SetCommand (the Command's setter) can be called from any ol' thread, setting the FCommand member is protected by the thread's critical section which is locked and unlocked through the Lock and Unlock methods.

Signalling MyEvent is done because our thread class uses a TEvent member to wait for work.

```
procedure TCommandThread.Execute;
begin
  LogDebug1.SendFmtMsg('%s.Execute : Started', [ClassName]);

  // keep running until we're terminated
  while not Terminated do
  try
    // wait until we're terminated or cleared for take-off by the threadpool
    if WaitForNewCommand then
      if  Assigned(FCommand)
      and not Terminated then
        // process the command if we're told to do so
        CommandExecute;

  except
    LogGeneral.SendFmtError('%s.Execute : Exception occurred :', [ClassName]);
    LogGeneral.SendException;
  end;

  LogDebug1.SendFmtMsg('%s.Execute : Finished', [ClassName]);
end;
```

WaitForNewCommand returns when the MyEvent is signalled. This is done when a command is assigned, but also when a (running) command is cancelled, when the thread is terminated etc. Note that Terminated is checked again just before CommandExecute is called. This is done because when WaitForNewCommand returns, we could be in a situation where both a command was assigned and terminate has been called. After all, signalling the event can be done twice from different threads and we don't know when or in what order anything happened.

CommandExecute is a virtual method that different thread classes can override. In the default implementation it provides for all the status processing around command execution so the commands themselves can concentrate on their own stuff.

```
procedure TCommandThread.CommandExecute;
var
  ExceptionMessage: string;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(FCommand), 'A nil command was passed to a command handler thread.');
  Assert(Status = chsIdle, 'Attempted to execute non-idle command handler thread');

  // check if the thread is ready for processing
  if IsAvailable then // if the thread is available, there is nothing to do...
    Exit;

  try
    FStatus := chsInitializing;
    InitializeCommand;

    FStatus := chsProcessing;
    try
      ExceptionMessage := '';
      CallCommandExecute;
    except
      on E: Exception do begin
        ExceptionMessage := E.Message;
        LogGeneral.SendFmtError('%s.CommandExecute: Exception occurred during commandhandler thread execution:', [ClassName]);
        LogGeneral.SendException;
      end;
    end;

  finally
      FStatus := chsFinalizing;
      FinalizeCommand;

      FStatus := chsIdle;
      FCommand := nil;

      // Notify threadpool we're done, so it can terminate this thread if necessary :
      DoThreadFinished;

      // Counterpart to ClaimThreadForProcessing which is checked in IsAvailable.
      ReleaseThreadForProcessing; 
  end;
end;
```

CallCommandExecute is where, through several levels of indirection the FCommand's Execute method is called and where the real work of the command is done. That is why that call is directly protected with a try-except block. Other than that each Command in and of itself is responsible for thread safety with regard to the resources it uses.

ClaimThreadForProcessing and ReleaseThreadForProcessing are used to claim and release a thread. For speed's sake they don't use the thread's lock, but use the interlocked mechanism to change the value of the class' FIsAvailable member which is declared as a pointer and used as a boolean:

```
TCommandThread = class(TThread)
  // ...
  FIsAvailable: Pointer;

function TCommandThread.ClaimThreadForProcessing: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Boolean(CompatibleInterlockedCompareExchange(FIsAvailable, Pointer(False), Pointer(True)));
  // (See InterlockedExchange help.)
end;

function TCommandThread.ReleaseThreadForProcessing: Boolean;
begin
  FIsAvailable := Pointer(True);
  Result := IsAvailable;
end;
```

If any of the "finally" processing in the CommandExecute method needs to be done regardless of exceptions raised by other calls in that process, you will have to use nested try-finally's to ensure that is the case. The above method was simplified from our real code and the actual finally block is a set of nested try finally's to ensure that DoThreadFinished etc. get called regardless of exceptions in FinalizeCommand (and other calls in between).

Comment: Whether or not the `OnExecute` event property needs protection depends on your threading rules. If you decree that it must never modified after the thread starts executing then there's no need for locking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok, but how would you "decree" this? Having a hard time imagining how you would accomplish this without a setter and if you have a setter then I can only think of some interlocked construct to prevent double / re assignment and ignoring/raising exception on any subsequent assignment. Then again, I am tired and no longer thinking that clearly.

Comment: It would be part of the interface contract. All parties would agree to it. No point adding extensive internal locking mechanisms to support issues that don't arise.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on your valuable input, it's a great help. It's nice to see that I'm not the only person who's done this, as most people are making it seem as if I'm wasting time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can see how that would work with a thread that you fire and forget, but can't see it for a thread that keeps running and processing commands that are thrown its way. Whether you do it in the worker thread, or in the "scheduler" that distributes commands to the available threads, you need some way to know whether it has a command assigned or not and that needs protection.

Comment: @Marjan You need to lock if you want to be able to assign the events whilst the thread is executing. If you don't need to support that then locking is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about how to make it safe to override `Execute`. Consumers who override your thread's `Execute` method won't work correctly (because they'll put their own operations *around* your bookkeeping code instead of *within* it). Provide a new virtual method for descendants to call instead. You could call it `Run`, for example, using Indy's `TIdThread` as a guide. It does much of the same things you're planning on.

Comment: So do you mean don't allow the user to inherit `Execute` but instead introduce a new replacement for `Execute` which is called from within my inherited `Execute`? That sounds reasonable...

Comment: PS I don't plan to distribute this :P It will be for internal use but will be widely used in many of my projects.

Comment: Right. Consumers of this class won't override `Execute`. If they do, they'll find that their code doesn't work, and they'll quickly stop. It's a self-correcting problem.

Comment: +1 That's a pattern I came across several times too...often this pairs of methods are called `DoCreate`, DoExecute` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the probably correct approach, however accepted Marjan's answer for two reasons, because he goes into much more detail and took the time to put code, and also was directly aimed at my goal of using an event rather than overriding the `Execute` procedure.

Comment: For the record, this is actually the approach which I wound up using. I'm finding myself debating on which answer to accept: The one with tons of info and aimed at my question, or the brief to the point one which I actually used?

Comment: Actually this is working beautifully :) I'm starting to wonder why I thought an `OnExecute` event would make things easier, it was actually much harder with what I was trying to do. Using actually the specific procedure name `Run` is perfect for what I'm doing. Thanks again, and I should have thought of that myself!

Comment: You should accept the best answer not the one that took the most effort (you can upvote this as well of course).

Answer (score 3):

Don't call Sleep(FExecDelay) - it's a kernel call that the descendant may not wish to make, so:

```
if (FExecDelay<>0) then Sleep(FExecDelay);
```

This gives a user the choice of avoiding the kernel call entirely.

I have issues with TThread.Synchronize - I would not want to force any user to have to call it.

TBH, I'm more used to putting code into an object class that is not descended from TThread, ie. a 'Ttask' that has a 'work' method that is called from the TThread.  Having a separate class for the work is hugely more flexible and safer than adding data members and methods to a TThread descendant - it's easily queued in, queued out, PostMessaged etc.  That, and not having access to the TThread instance stops developers using TThread.Synchronize, TThread.WaitFor and TThread.OnTerminate, so increasing the reliability and performance of the app.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll give that some thought

Comment: TThread.Synchronize has been available as a class method for many releases; its use is not restricted to TThread descendants.

Comment: +1 for putting code into a class not descendent from TThread.

Comment: In general, once you take out all the bad ideas, there's no code left in Jerry's class. Ergo, I wonder why have it.  I understand the idea of a worker thread, but this isn't how to do it. I wish I could think of a general worker class that would help Jerry and I would try to help instead of just complaining, but I really don't know what he really needs to do.

Comment: @RobKennedy - I self-restricted my use of TThread.Synchronize to 'never'.  IIRC, it was round about 1998 when I got D3.  My first threaded app deadlocked on shutdown because of Synchronize.  When I worked out what was happening and how Synchronize/WaitFor/OnTerminate worked, I banned myself from using them.